# Inheritance Inversion in React to traverse the whole tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inheritance, inversion

I'm trying to build an HOC in React that manipulates all react elements mounted in the tree passed in argument. I use the inheritance inversion pattern described  [here](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e).

For the example, the manipulation will consist in adding the foo props with "PASSED !!" as value to every *Child* element in the Component named *Parent*. I have the following tree where all *Child* elements display their name, their children if ones and the value of foo prop:

```
const Child = ({ foo }) => <div> Child {foo}  </div>
const NestedChild = ({ foo }) => <div> NestedChild {foo} </div>
const ChildWithNested1 = ({ foo, children }) => <div> ChildWithNested1 {foo} {children} </div>
const ChildWithNested2 = ({ foo }) => <div> ChildWithNested2 {foo} <NestedChild /> </div>

class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child />
        <ChildWithNested1>
          <NestedChild />
        </ChildWithNested1>
        <ChildWithNested2 />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The goal is to pass the foo prop to each Child elements, even the nested ones. I build a simple HOC that traverse the tree recursively:

```
const HOC = (component) => {
  return class WrappedComponent extends component {

    traverseTree = (tree) => {
      if (tree.props.children) {
        const newChildren = React.Children.map(tree.props.children, (item) => this.traverseTree(item))
        const newTree = React.cloneElement(tree, { foo: 'PASSED !!' }, newChildren)
        return newTree
      }
      else if (React.isValidElement(tree)) {
        const newProps = Object.assign({}, tree.props, { foo: 'PASSED !!' })
        return React.cloneElement(tree, newProps, tree.props.children)
      }
      else {
        return tree
      }
    }

    render() {
      return this.traverseTree(super.render())
    }
  }
}

export default HOC(Parent);
```

And I get this result in the browser:

```
Child PASSED !!
ChildWithNested1 PASSED !!
NestedChild PASSED !!
ChildWithNested2 PASSED !!
NestedChild
```

So the HOC works as expected, all child elements receive the foo prop except the second *NestedChild* element which is directly invoked in *ChildWithNested2*, so not included in the *props.children* object, and therefore not reached by the *traverseTree* function in the HOC.

So my question is:

Is it possible to make an HOC that reaches every react element to get this result:

```
 Child PASSED !!
 ChildWithNested1 PASSED !!
 NestedChild PASSED !!
 ChildWithNested2 PASSED !!
 NestedChild PASSED !!
```

Secondly, is there a way to write a function that modify only the users-named react elements (not html tags elements like div)?

Comment: `ChildWithNested2` doesn't have children that are passed via props.

Comment: Yes indeed, the question is how I reach the NestedChild invoked in ChildWithNested2 knowing that NestedChild is not really a chil in that case.